# how to get top 2 entries from each day in a week in MySql 5.5.34

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with columns **TENANT_NAME**, **MAX_CALLS**, and **TIME_STAMP** and there is **no primary key**,  as per requirement for every hour we are inserting data and the same names can be repeated.

now I want to fetch like need to add group names and sum calls and fetch the top 2 entries per day in a week.

Ex: data insert at 22:49

```
TENANT_NAME,MAX_CALLS,TIME_STAMP
RS1, 20, 2022-12-07 22:49:17
RS2, 10, 2022-12-07 22:49:17
RS3, 2, 2022-12-07 22:49:17
```

in the next hour at 23:49

```
RS1, 15, 2022-12-07 23:49:17
RS2, 0, 2022-12-07 23:49:17
RS3, 20, 2022-12-07 23:49:17
```

like this, I have 1 year of data

now i want per day aggregation of groups of name 2 records of a week

like this

```
RS1, 35, MON
RS3, 22, MON... so on
RS4, 40, SUN
RS2, 35, SUN
```

I tried this query and I am able to group names and sum total calls, and display DAYNAME but I want the top 2 records per day of in a week.

```
select a.TENANT_NAME,SUM(a.MAX_CALLS),DAYNAME(a.TIME_STAMP) from TENANT_LIC_DISTRIBUTION AS a group by a.TENANT_NAME,day(a.TIME_STAMP) order by a.MAX_CALLS,a.TIME_STAMP;

RS1, 35, MON
RS3, 22, MON
RS2, 10, MON

RS3, 30, TUE
RS2, 20, TUE
RS1, 10, TUE.... so on
RS1, 20, SUN
RS2, 10, SUN
RS3, 1, SUN
```

and I want to fetch like this

```
RS1, 35, MON
RS3, 22, MON

RS3, 30, TUE
RS2, 20, TUE.... so on

RS1, 20, SUN
RS2, 10, SUN
```

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) around your aggregation query to append row numbers, and then limit by row number. Here's one way.

```
WITH rank_tenant
AS (
    SELECT TENANT_NAME, 
    DAY, 
    CALLS, 
    row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY TENANT_NAME 
            ORDER BY CALLS DESC
            ) AS row_num
    FROM (select 
          TENANT_NAME,
          DAYNAME(TIME_STAMP) as DAY,
          SUM(MAX_CALLS) as CALLS
          from TENANT_LIC_DISTRIBUTION
          group by TENANT_NAME, DAY) as t1
    )
SELECT TENANT_NAME,
    DAY,
    CALLS
FROM rank_tenant
WHERE row_num <= 2;
```

Comment: it is throwing an syntax error bro. is this rank_tenant is my table name?

Comment: rank_tenant is just the CTE name. What version do you have running? What is the error message?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank_tenant AS (SELECT TENANT_NAME,DAY,CALLS,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TEN' at line 1

Comment: Server version: 5.5.34 MySQL Community Server

Comment: Yes, you'll need to be on at least version 8.0 of MySQL to use CTEs or window functions. This solution will not work on 5.5.

Comment: but do i have any other alternatives in this version bro

Comment: I don't have another method handy, Harish.